# Passing an Int64 from .net service to Javascript using BigInt

Tags: javascript, bigint, int64

I am trying to pass an `Int64` number from a `.Net` service into javascript while maintain the precision using `BigInt`.

It seems however that Javascript is rounding this number before I can cast it as a BigInt.

In the service, I am returning the Int64 number `636904216084035679`.

The following Javascript calls this service, and logs both a BigInt and JS number. The results are `636904216084035712n` and `636904216084035700` respectively.

```
Services.ClientService.GetClientToken(function (clientToken)
{
  console.log(BigInt(clientToken));
  console.log(clientToken);
  resolve(BigInt(clientToken));
}, function ()
  {
    reject();
  });
```

Clearly the 'clientToken' variable is being incorrectly set as a number type when the function is called which is losing the accuracy required. Any thoughts on how to pass Int64 numbers from a service?

Comment: You could send `clientToken` as a string and then `BigInt(clientToken)`

Comment: @adiga Good point, should have thought of that!